# Is there a permalink to the latest version of Joomla (zip archive)?

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to automate WHM to download and install Joomla into any new cPanel accounts I create, rather than doing it manually each time. However I can't find any permalink to the latest version of Joomla that I can use to grab the required zip. Does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly unlike WordPress and other content managements Joomla as far as I know have opted not to use `latest.zip` but rather use a version with the file name.

Your best bet would be to subscribe to Joomla's RSS feed at http://feeds.joomla.org/JoomlaSecurityNews and look out for new updates then login to your administrator panel and do the click update.

***WordPress now auto updates...***

It's worth mentioning that WordPress as of 3.7.1 includes a automated and unattended update feature, maybe Joomla will follow suit.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for the confirmation - I'll maybe try and parse the RSS feed within my automation script.

Comment: Joomla Already have it, When you check Joomla Admin panel It Shows  new update available How they doing It ? look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For Long Term Support (LTS) branch -( Recommended) Stable release

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml
```

Short term support (STS) branch

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/sts/list_sts.xml
```

Testing versions.

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/test/list_test.xml
```

All these XML files have link to their details zip files.

You have to look at the last node of each XML file for getting latest version.

Hope it helps..